# jquery tabs linking only to main index

Tags: jquery, url, tabs, hyperlink

Hi I'm having some tab url problems.
On my [main site](http://blackflow.pl) under the main slider I have a box with tabs [(tabs I was using)](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html). Problem start when you go to others pages ([other page](http://www.blackflow.pl/www.html)). When you click tabs on other pages it redirects to index. 
On the main page, links look like that: blackflow.pl/#tab_name. 
I've tried to add sites url: blackflow.pl/different_page.html#tab_name but it doesn't help.
Any ideas? hope it's descriptive enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a base tag set on your head:

```
<base href="http://www.blackflow.pl/" />
```

You can read more about it here: http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp
Basically, any links you have will be relative to the base you have set. Take that away and your tabs should work fine. If it is not required, I suggest you take it out. Make sure there's nothing depending on it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event.preventDefault(); on the tab click handlers. Whats happening right now is that your tabs click handler is allowing the #whatever to be sent to the browser and it thinks it should go to the root of the site and try to find the anchor #whatever.